# Handling multiple ajax http requests using Observables

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have angular2 website which sends multiple ajax requests using Json Web Tokens for authorization, when it starts up

Here are they:

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.token.access_token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/profile', options)
        .map(response => response.json() as User).catch(this.handleError);
}


public getFriends(): Observable<User[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.token.access_token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/users/${this.authService.userId}/friends`, options)
        .map(response => response.json() as User[]).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And so on

But I need access token to do this request
I store it and refresh token in local storage, but access token expires in 5min

So when user logins access and refresh tokens are stored in local storage

If user closes his browser after logging in, waits for 5 or more minutes and then opens page again we need to refresh it (with another request) and THEN send our requests

And here is the main problem: We don't know how many or what request will be send, so we can't just hardcode it

Here is update request

```
 public update(): Observable<boolean> {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });


        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return  this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/token', "refresh_token=" + encodeURIComponent(this.token.refresh_token) + "&grant_type=refresh_token", options)
            .map((response: Response) => {

                let token = response.json();
                if (token) {
                    this.token = token;
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({
                        token: this.token,
                        userId: this.userId
                    }));
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }).catch(this.handleError);  

}
```

if do something like this:

```
this.authService.update().flatMap(this.getUser);
```

It  won't help because we will send a lot of "update" requests, which won't result in anything good for us

Sending only "update" request won't help either because we will send one "update" and a lot of other requests

So what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Let me see if I got it right. You want to make sure that: a) you're not spamming server with avalanche of "update" requests; b) you still need to make update call when you make any other call after 5 minutes have passed since last update. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov Yes

Answer (score 0):

It is deemed unsafe to store access tokens in local storage. Any local script could have access to it.

So while is not what you requests, I'll suggest using http-only cookies. Cookies have a set expiration, so that would help your requirement.

```
Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
```

This cookie is sent automatically with HTTPXMLRequest (angular/http underlying access).

Then whenever a request fails because the token expired, you can catch, generate another token, then retry:

```
http.get(...)
    .catch(obs => {
       return refreshToken().mergeMapTo(obs);
    })
```

Because it is http-only, no script can access it, that's why it needs to re-do after it fails, i.e. you can figure in advance.

Comment: I can't use cookies for authorization, server requires Authorization header, also this does not solve problem with many requests failing at the same time, because ALL failed requests will send update request